# Proguard config for facebook sdk. Strip everything except analytics

Tags: android, facebook, proguard

I want to use the facebook sdk just for analytics, is there an optimized proguard configuration that I could use to strip out the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was wrong, there is no way to strip the code in proguard, probably it can be done playing with exclusions in gradle, but I do not think is doable using just proguard

In any case facebook finally has modularised their sdk, so for people like me that are insterested just on analytics, facebook-core is the only depedency we need to import

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to huge size, it is mostly about the resources rather than worrying about minimising java code itself. So you could actually try out a few things mentioned below.

1. Proguard works on the Java code. Unfortunately, it doesn’t work on the resources folder. As a consequence, if an image my_image in res/drawable is not used, Proguard only strips it’s reference in the R class but keeps the associated image in place.
2. Lint is a static code analyzer that helps you to detect all unused resources with a simple call to ./gradlew lint. It generates an HTML-report and gives you the exhaustive list of resources that look unused under the “UnusedResources: Unused resources” section. It is safe to remove these resources as long as you don’t access them through reflection in your code.

However Lint can tell you where are unused resources, but with fb sdk it will be hard to delete the resources as it comes from maven repository.

**Minimising Resource Configuration (build.gradle)**
For eg Fb sdk provides support all languages which you might not need, or all folders images like mdpi which may not be useful for you.

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en", "de", "fr", "it"
    resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
}
```

If all of this doesn't work that means either native code is bloating your apk, where application binary interface split might help reducing your apk size.

ABI Split:-

```
 splits {
        density {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "ldpi", "mdpi"
        }
        abi {

            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

I think something could be done here as I opened facebook sdk gradle file ... it has few transitive dependencies, which is redundant and might conflict with your support version so you could either import the same in your files

```
dependencies {
    // Facebook Dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'}
```

It could be removed from final fat jar as you might be already using the support dependencies in your project that too different or conflicting ones .. so you could ideally exclude transitive dependencies based on your requirements something like below

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support' //by group
    }
```

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for but IMO the best answer :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help but I think what could be done here is I opened facebook sdk gradle file ... it has few transitive dependencies

Answer (score -1):

The [ProGuard config included in the Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/proguard-project.txt) has been updated and so it will correctly remove all classes that are not being used by your app (e.g. everything not in Analytics).

... except for anything `Serializable` which Facebook feels it is unsafe to remove ...

It now looks a lot like the older answers around here:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

(as of [20 May 2016](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/5d0186f065b9ed4ff185234c860c7455343f1f39))

Which means that **we don't need our own ProGuard settings for Facebook** anymore. Gradle will automatically use the rules supplied by the SDK.

---

Of course, this still requires that your `build.gradle` is configured to run ProGuard:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.pro'
```

Comment: fine, but how can I strip everything except the analytics stuff?

Comment: @dmarin That config *will* strip everything except the analytics stuff, if you are using the analytics in your app. I am interested to know if this does not solve the problem, after my update to require Gradle, because it works for me. Perhaps I have left something out that I thought was not important to this answer? (I have added the Gradle `minify Enabled true` config now)

Comment: Sorry I think I am misunderstanding this, so let me explain it on different words to double check. We do not need to add anything in the proguard config cause everything is done for free, is that what you mean? In that case the analytics relate code is just crazy big (0.5 megs and about 4k methods?)

Comment: That's what I meant, but it does seem like a lot of methods. However Analytics is not a simple feature, requiring web comms, saving temp files, logging into their server etc. The default config does strip out a whole lot of other unused stuff (I currently ship with their `LoginFragment` because I was overriding their own rules), but I didn't analyse exactly what was left behind.

Comment: This needs some more thought - how much does the default config leave behind which is NOT directly linked to Analytics? And can we override this default config? I'll not have much time this week for this, but feel free to edit/post if you find more useful info. ProGuard is, and always has been, a big problem for me but I, like you, am trying to get rid of as much as is safely possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
 *;
} 
-keepattributes Signature
```

I use these 2 lines and working everything fine

Comment: This is not needed, Facebook includes his own proguard config.